# expecting a right parentheses, found ','

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirment to calculate distance between 2 locations. I am using dynamic soql to query data.below is my soql. but I am getting below error:

> expecting a right parentheses, found ','

what I read is that distance do not accept geolocation as first parameter, Moreover giving geolocation a field as parameter is also not valid i think. Any idea why i am getting this error

```
SELECT Id, Name, Type, Phone, Account_Group__c, Geolocation__c, Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s, ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, CDO_Size__c, GDO_Size__c, PAS_Size__c FROM Account WHERE Is_Primary_Account__c=false AND BillingLatitude != null AND BillingLongitude != null ORDER BY DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(BillingLatitude,BillingLongitude), GEOLOCATION(24.974828,67.056598), 'mi') NULLS LAST LIMIT 60
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Type, Phone, Account_Group__c, Geolocation__c, Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s, ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, CDO_Size__c, GDO_Size__c, PAS_Size__c FROM Account WHERE Is_Primary_Account__c=false AND BillingLatitude != null AND BillingLongitude != null ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(24.974828,67.056598), 'mi') NULLS LAST LIMIT 60
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm?search_text=distance) states this:

> Usage: DISTANCE(mylocation1, mylocation2, 'unit') and replace
>   mylocation1 and mylocation2 with two location fields, or a location
>   field and a value returned by the GEOLOCATION function. Replace unit
>   with mi (miles) or km (kilometers)

Thus the first parameter should be a "location field" meaning either a custom geolocation field (compound) or a standard address field (like BillingAddress).

Your first parameter (GEOLOCATION(BillingLatitude, Longitude)) is not a location field.

Comment: Giving explanation to the root cause for OP's question would be great.

Comment: You're right, sorry. The documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm?search_text=distance) states this: 
Usage: DISTANCE(mylocation1, mylocation2, 'unit') and replace mylocation1 and mylocation2 with two location fields, or a location field and a value returned by the GEOLOCATION function. Replace unit with mi (miles) or km (kilometers)
Thus the first parameter should be a "location field" meaning either a custom geolocation field (compound) or a standard address field (like BillingAddress).